# Folder as parameter in PHP

Tags: php

I want to create a script that pass every folder requested in a website as a parameter.

For example, if someone requests:

```
www.example.com/foo
```

...that will be redirected to the main index.php and passed as a parameter, getting the same result when requesting `www.example.com/index.php?foo`

Please note that the folder requested will be random so i can't predict the folder and put a php script there.

Should i handle all the 404 requests through HTACCESS? **Or there's a fancier solution?**

Comment: What webserver are you using? The answer will depend heavily on that as it's handled at that level, not at the PHP level.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to clarify that: I'm using Apache, with mod_rewrite enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using htaccess is a solution.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

That one will rewrite url not followed by index.php, images or robots.txt to /index.php?{DIR OR VARS}

Answer (score 6):

In your url `foo` is a parameter key, if you mean to have it like that then what value would it have?

Perhaps your confusing it with a routing structure where you pass the entire url to a routing script that handles the request

The rewrite your looking for is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in your index you split the url like this:

```
<?php 
$parts = isset($_GET['route']) ? explode('/',$_GET['route']) : array();
?>
```

Then an example URL would look like:
`www.example.com/foo/bar/baz`

```
$parts[0] = foo
$parts[1] = bar
$parts[2] = baz
```

then if your looking for a folders/files existence, something like this:

```
<?php 
if (isset($parts[0]) && file_exists('./'.basename($parts[0]))) {
    //Folder or file exists
} else {
    //Folder or file does not exist - 404
}
?>
```

Comment: It will have no value, just the parameter is enough. Still, when someone types example.com/foo and the foo folder doesn't exist, the php script will not be executed and a 404 message will appear, right? Or the rewritenegine catches everything?

Comment: It passes everything, its the php part that decides what to show.

Comment: @Andres: By default, RewriteEngine will hide existing files. That's what the `!-f` line is for, to display actual files (only run the rule if the REQUEST_FILENAME isn't an actual file). Everything else will get passed through to PHP, which can do whatever it wants.

Comment: Mega stupid question: So the RewriteEngine part goes in the HTACCESS file, rather than in the index.php?

Comment: yes in a file called .htaccess (lowercase), also make sure `mod_rewrite.so` is enabled in your apache config else it wont work

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called **url rewrite**. There is a lot of information about it in the net.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Apache.

Sounds like what you really need is a RewriteRule, check out mod_rewrite here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "[routing](http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/)" where the url's "folders" are turned into parameters called "segments".

As far as I know, you need an "entry point, usually" the top level `index.php` where the rest of the path is parsed.

```
http://example.com/index.php/foo/bar/baz
                      ^----entry point
```

the `index.php` part can be removed via a server rewrite rule, leaving you with

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz
```

This is a more "scalable" way since you'll only be editing the "url parser" logic in PHP (usually loaded as an include in `index.php`) rather than editing the `.htaccess` or the server's url rewrite file. This gives you more control over routing, especially in hosting sites that don't allow editing the server's configuration files.

Comment: But still, i will not be able to call example.com/foo/bar/baz because those folders doesn't exist. This will only work as long as the url is requested with the index.php in the middle, right?

Comment: @Andres you won't need folders for this method. the segments will only be used like parameters. also, it does need the `index.php` but you can remove it using a rewrite rule like what the other answers have stated.