# What will happen after this request in php

Tags: php, html, http

I see some weird code in a site. I am very confused about this. There is the http request that I tested my own server:

```html
http://192.168.1.3/folder/ui/login_html.php/TEST/TEST
```

The folder named login_html.php and TEST are **not exist**.I checked the debug information for Chrome.It can properly request files but cannot parse it.[debug information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8TuA.jpg)
.
It seems that will request all css and js resources which referenced in the login_html.php, And the request is initiated by **TEST**.
By the way, I did nothing in login_html.php, I just reference files and write some html code.
There is an apache information in **access_log** and nothing in **error_log**:

```
"GET /cos/ui/login_html.php/TEST/js/cloudmanager.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9564 "http://192.168.1.3/cos/ui/login_html.php/TEST/TEST" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
```

I am confused about this.And can someone explain it?

Comment: It's a correct request parameter made by editing htaccess.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424644/folder-as-parameter-in-php

Comment: _"What will happen in the php server."_ - It depends what you do with it. There's nothing in PHP itself that will automatically do anything with it.

Answer (score -1):

Everything after the `?` is the query string.
Often this contains variables in the form `var1=value1&var2=value2`. In that case, PHP parses these automatically and puts them in the `$_GET` array.

In your example the query string doesn't contain a normal set of variables, so the `$_GET` array would likely be little use. However, you could just get the entire query string from the `$_SERVER` array.

```
$var = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
// $var would be "/HOME/getVersion"
```